# Serving TF model with Variable length input

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to serve my TF model with TF Serving. Here's the model's input I have:

```
raw_feature_spec = {
     'x': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
     'y': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
     'z': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
}
```

Then input object gets transformed using TF Transform with Beam into object with shapes x:(None, 20, 100), y:(None, 20, 5), z:(None,3), which are applicable for initial model without transform_funс (Transform Graph) included. Then I'm exporting my model with:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import tensorflow_transform as tft

 tf_transform_output = tft.TFTransformOutput('saved_transform_graph_folder')     
 estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model_path='model_folder')
 estimator.export_saved_model('OUTPUT_MODEL_NAME',  make_serving_input_fn(tf_transform_output))

def make_serving_input_fn(tf_transform_output):
 raw_feature_spec = {
       'x': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
       'y': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
       'z': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
   }

def serving_input_fn():
    raw_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(raw_feature_spec)
    raw_reatures = raw_input_fn().features
    features = {
        'x': tf.sparse.to_dense(raw_reatures["x"]),
        'y':  tf.sparse.to_dense(raw_reatures["y"]),
        'z': raw_reatures["z"]
    }

    # Apply the transform function that was used to generate the materialized data
    transformed_features = tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(raw_reatures)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(transformed_features, features)

return serving_input_fn
```

Where transform_func is some func, which reshapes input tensors to the ones needed and is included into tf_transform_output object. 
So when I serve exported model by this code using TFS image from Docker Hub, sending HTTP GET request to /model/metadata I'm getting:

```
{
"model_spec": {
    "name": "newModel",
    "signature_name": "",
    "version": "1579786077"
},
"metadata": {
    "signature_def": {
        "signature_def": {
            "serving_default": {
                "inputs": {
                    "x": {
                        "dtype": "DT_STRING",
                        "tensor_shape": {
                            "dim": [
                                {
                                    "size": "-1",
                                    "name": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "size": "-1",
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "unknown_rank": false
                        },
                        "name": "SparseToDense_1:0"
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "dtype": "DT_STRING",
                        "tensor_shape": {
                            "dim": [
                                {
                                    "size": "-1",
                                    "name": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "size": "-1",
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "unknown_rank": false
                        },
                        "name": "SparseToDense:0"
                    },
                    "z": {
                        "dtype": "DT_STRING",
                        "tensor_shape": {
                            "dim": [
                                {
                                    "size": "-1",
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "unknown_rank": false
                        },
                        "name": "ParseExample/ParseExample:6"
                    }
                },
                "outputs": {
                    "main_output": {
                        "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                        "tensor_shape": {
                            "dim": [
                                {
                                    "size": "-1",
                                    "name": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "size": "20",
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "unknown_rank": false
                        },
                        "name": "main_output/Softmax:0"
                    }
                },
                "method_name": "tensorflow/serving/predict"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the inputs are correct (nevertheless I used tf.sparse.to_dense for casing of VarLenFeature while exporting). But when I send HTTP POST request to /model:predict with body:

```
{ 
   "instances": 
   [
     {
        "x": ["text","text","text","text","text","text"],
        "y": ["test","test","test","test","test","test"],
        "z": "str"
     }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting an error

```
{
    "error": "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor \'input_example_tensor\' with dtype string and shape [?]\n\t [[{{node input_example_tensor}}]]"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong or how to create Variable input correctly? I need Tensors shapes as I now have in metadata, so I don't need an ability to access API by serialized proto Example, just by raw tensors.
TF version: 2.0, TF Serving and TF Transform - last versions.

**P.S.** Also, I've tried to export a model using *tf.keras.backend.placeholder* with *build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn* call so there would be no casting from sparse to dense tensor in serving_input_fn, but results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have a placeholder named `input_example_tensor` in the `transformed_features`. And also the sparse placeholder of TensorFlow doesn't work.

I solve this problem by representing each sparse tensor with 3 dense tensors in the receiver, namely indices, values, and shape then convert them to sparse tensor in features. For your case, you need to define the `serving_input_fn` as following:

```
def serving_input_fn():
    inputs = {
        "x_indices": tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, 2]),
        "x_vals": tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None, 2]),
        "x_shape": tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [2]),
        "y_indices": tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, 2]),
        "y_vals": tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None, 2]),
        "y_shape": tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [2]),
        "z": tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None, 1])
    }

    fvs = {
        "x": tf.SparseTensor(
                 inputs["x_indices"],
                 inputs["x_vals"],
                 inputs[x_shape]
             ),
        "y": tf.SparseTensor(
                 inputs["y_indices"],
                 inputs["y_vals"],
                 inputs[y_shape]
             ),
        "z": inputs["z"]
    }
    
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(fvs, inputs)
```

I also want to ask you a question, how did you manage to train a model that has VarLenFeature with TensorFlow Keras, could you share this part with me? Currently, I'm training this kind of models with TensorFlow Estimator.

Comment: Hi, Wenmin. Thank you for your reply. I was considering such solution. But for the client, using my served model, this is not convenient, since it's not Python code. So I've found a different, more hacky solution. This has some limitations, i.e. I can't send different sized tensors like 3 words in _x_ and 5 words in _y_, and the size of tensors is limited to 20 in Transform code, which goes right after serving request. But still, it's fine for me. I think it can be further tuned. [Here's it.](https://gist.github.com/DmitriyBaykov/a92ac2e8c59724e0c4d7e63685fb324b)

Comment: As for training a model - I'm using Tensorflow Transform before it, so my full data preprocessing stays there and I'm having fixed-size tensors after it (I'm converting Sparse tensors (VarLenFeature) to Dense and I have equally fixed-size tensors in the end). Let me know if you need more details here. Unfortunately, I didn't found a workable solution to train on sparse tensors, but there is a param in Keras Input layer, which determines whether it's a sparse tensor or not (named _sparse_ = True/False). You can also try to experiment with that thing.